# Are there formulas for sums of products of unitary matrices of the form $\sum_i U_{ij}U_{il}U_{ik}^* U_{im}^*$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthonormal

If $U$ is unitary, then by definition
$$\sum_i U_{ij}U_{ik}^* = \delta_{jk}\tag1$$
holds.

What about products of more than two copies of the same unitary matrix?
Consider for example the following product of four copies of the same unitary matrix:

$$\sum_i U_{ij}U_{il}U_{ik}^* U_{im}^*.\tag2$$
Can something be said in this case? Does a variation of **(1)** hold?

Comment: The product in (1) is nothing but a component form of the matrix identity $UU^\dagger = I$. Your expression (2) is not on this form and the index being summed over is in all 4 matrices so I doubt it.

Comment: of course (1) is nothing but that, hence why it is an immediate consequence of $U$ being unitary. The question is exactly whether formulas like that hold for products of more than two $U_{ij}$. I guess there is no closed "nice" formula for something like that then?

Comment: What I was trying to say is that formulas on this form tends to be component forms of matrix identities. The fact that (2) is not on this form due to the free index in all 4 matrices makes it, IMO, highly unlikely something exists here. You can try to investigate this yourself: for example take a general form for a $2\times 2$ unitary matrix and compute the $16$ different components in (2) and see if there is any pattern.